# Django and postgresql testing schema

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-testing

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and Django 1.7.4 with psycopg2 2.5.4

The DBA, asked us to create a schema for our application instead of using public.

We defined the schema, and we had to add the

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'options': '-c search_path=custom-schema-name'
},
```

to the settings.

During testing, Django is creating the test database with the corresponding name, but we can't set the custom-schema name

I tried to find a way to set up the custom schema name (I've read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEST)) but I can't find a way to force the creation of the schema name during testing.

The error that I obtain is

*django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in*

When I see the created database , it has the schema public created by default.

I partially solved this issue and added to the search path the schema name public

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'options': '-c search_path=custom-schema-name,public'
},
```

but I'd like to create the test database with a custom schema name.

Does anybody knows how to set the testing schema name ?

Comment: same issue here - do you found a solution, you might want share? :)

Comment: No, I've never found the solution. I've left the job and I totally forgot about this question here. It has been a year since I posted this, and yours is the only answer so far.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to have django use non-public schema. There appears to be a thread about this here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22673#no1 to fix in django, alternatively I have found this possible solution: https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up with writing a custom test runner to solve this problem (using django 1.9.x):

**myapp/test/runner.py**

```
from types import MethodType
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from django.db import connections

def prepare_database(self):
    self.connect()
    self.connection.cursor().execute("""
    CREATE SCHEMA foobar_schema AUTHORIZATION your_user;
    GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA foobar_schema TO your_user;
    """)


class PostgresSchemaTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        for connection_name in connections:
            connection = connections[connection_name]
            connection.prepare_database = MethodType(prepare_database, connection)
        return super().setup_databases(**kwargs)
```

**settings.py**

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'myapp.test.runner.PostgresSchemaTestRunner'
```

Comment: Thx, this saved me a lot of debugging. Still works like charm for postgres 11.x, django 2.2.x and psycopg 2.8.x.

Comment: How to disable foreign key constraint when truncate table?

is that possible to use teardown_databases() in runner?

Comment: @KodeKite disable triggers beforehand