# Hasura Computed no schema has been selected to create in. null

Tags: postgresql, hasura

So basiclly i want to create a computed field which is very basic, Get the full name from the database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION author_full_name(user_row users)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  SELECT user_row.firstName || ' ' || user_row.lastName
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Here is the users table:
users id int, firstName text, lastName text

db ss: https://ibb.co/gm1xzK2

I always end up with this error : "SQL Execution Failed
no schema has been selected to create in. null"

Comment: Did you set Function Schema for function as it shown here: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/_images/computed-field-create1.png ?

Comment: The function_name doesn't appear because the SQL is not working because of the error

Comment: So if you add `public` to `CREATE FUNCTION public.author_full_name`  as @Jesse Carter suggested - it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either fully qualify the schema where the function should be created eg `public.author_full_name` or update the search path in Postgres so that it defaults to a schema (public or otherwise)

See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41207765/1364771

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help out